# why the layout created programmatically in Android is created initially but not created afterwards

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I received a data list from the server and based on that list, I programmatically created layouts and views. The layout is composed of a ConstraintLayout containing TextView, RadioGroup, and RadioButtons. When I initially launch the app, the layouts are displayed correctly. However, when I navigate back to the same screen again, only one ConstraintLayout is shown. Upon debugging, I confirmed that constraintLayoutList contains more than one data.

I control fragments using Jetpack Navigation.

```
class BleTestFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentBleTestBinding>(FragmentBleTestBinding::inflate) {
    private val viewModel: MainViewModel by activityViewModels()

    private val dataList = arrayListOf<Code>()
    private val constraintLayoutList = arrayListOf<ConstraintLayout>()
    private val textViewList = arrayListOf<AppCompatTextView>()
    private val radioGroupList = arrayListOf<RadioGroup>()
    private val radioButtonList = arrayListOf<MaterialRadioButton>()
    private lateinit var testBtn : MaterialButton

    private var passFailList  = arrayListOf<String>()


    override fun configureUi() {
        testBtn = MaterialButton(requireContext())
    }
   

    override fun observeViewModel() {

        //Code for generating layout
        viewModel.appCommonCode.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            dataList.addAll(it.list)

            for (index in 0 until dataList.size){
                val constraintLayout = ConstraintLayout(requireContext())
                constraintLayout.id = View.generateViewId()
                constraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(),R.color.light_gray_color))
                constraintLayout.setPadding(10,10,10,10)
                val layoutParams =
                    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.height7)
                    )
                layoutParams.setMargins(10,20,10,0)
                constraintLayout.layoutParams = layoutParams
                constraintLayoutList.add(constraintLayout)
            }


            for (i in 0 until constraintLayoutList.size){
                val params = constraintLayoutList[i].layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                if (i == 0){
                    params.startToStart = ConstraintSet.START
                    params.endToEnd = ConstraintSet.END
                    params.topToTop = ConstraintSet.TOP
                    params.bottomToTop = constraintLayoutList[1].id
                }else if (i<constraintLayoutList.size-1){
                    params.startToStart = ConstraintSet.START
                    params.endToEnd = ConstraintSet.END
                    params.topToBottom = constraintLayoutList[i-1].id
                    params.bottomToTop = constraintLayoutList[i+1].id
                }else{
                    params.startToStart = ConstraintSet.START
                    params.endToEnd = ConstraintSet.END
                    params.topToBottom = constraintLayoutList[i-1].id
                    params.bottomToBottom = ConstraintSet.BOTTOM
                }
                constraintLayoutList[i].requestLayout()
            }

            for (index in 0 until it.list.size){
                val textView = AppCompatTextView(requireContext())
                textView.text = it.list[index].displayCode
                textView.id = View.generateViewId()
                textView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.black))
                textView.textSize = 20f
                textView.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
                val layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                textView.layoutParams = layoutParams
                textViewList.add(textView)
            }

            for (index in 0 until it.list.size){
                passFailList.add("")

                val radioGroup = RadioGroup(requireContext())
                radioGroup.id = View.generateViewId()

                val layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                radioGroup.layoutParams = layoutParams
                radioGroup.orientation = RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL
                val radioButtonArray = arrayListOf<MaterialRadioButton>()

                for (index2 in 0..1){
                    val radioButton = MaterialRadioButton(requireContext())
                    val layoutParams2 = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.height7),ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
                    layoutParams2.setMargins(20,20,20,20)
                    radioButton.layoutParams = layoutParams2
                    radioButton.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                    radioButton.buttonDrawable = null
                    if (index2 == 0){
                        radioButton.text = "PASS"
                        radioButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.selector_green_radio)
                    }else{
                        radioButton.text = "FAIL"
                        radioButton.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), R.drawable.selector_red_radio)
                    }

                    if (index == it.list.size-1){
                        radioButton.isEnabled = false
                    }

                    radioGroup.addView(radioButton)
                    radioButtonArray.add(radioButton)
                    radioButtonList.add(radioButton)
                }



                radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener { group, checkedId ->
                    when(checkedId){
                        radioButtonArray[0].id -> {
                            if (radioButtonArray[0].isChecked){
                                passFailList[index] = "PASS"
                            }
                        }
                        else -> {
                            if (radioButtonArray[1].isChecked){
                                passFailList[index] = "FAIL"
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (passFailList.any{it.isEmpty()}){
                        binding.statusText.text =  ""
                    }else if (passFailList.any{it == "FAIL"} || deviceStatus == "FAIL" || batteryTest == "FAIL"){
                        binding.statusText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.red_color))
                        binding.statusText.text =  "FAIL"
                    }else{
                        binding.statusText.text =  "PASS"
                        binding.statusText.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), R.color.green_color))
                    }
                }

                radioGroupList.add(radioGroup)
            }

            testBtn.text = "start"
            testBtn.id = View.generateViewId()
            testBtn.textSize = 20f
            testBtn.typeface = Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD
            val layoutParams = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.height5))
            testBtn.layoutParams = layoutParams

            testBtn.setOnClickListener {
                showProgress()
            }


            for (index in 0 until constraintLayoutList.size){
                constraintLayoutList[index].addView(textViewList[index])
                constraintLayoutList[index].addView(radioGroupList[index])

                if (index == constraintLayoutList.size-1){
                    testBtn.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
                        topToTop = constraintLayoutList[index].id
                        bottomToBottom = constraintLayoutList[index].id
                        startToEnd = textViewList[index].id
                        endToStart = radioGroupList[index].id
                    }
                    constraintLayoutList[index].addView(testBtn)
                }
            }


            for (constraintLayout in constraintLayoutList){
                binding.checkboxContainer.addView(constraintLayout)
            }

            for (index in 0 until constraintLayoutList.size){
                textViewList[index].updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
                    topToTop = constraintLayoutList[index].id
                    bottomToBottom = constraintLayoutList[index].id
                    startToStart = constraintLayoutList[index].id
                }

                val constraintLayout: ConstraintLayout = constraintLayoutList[index]
                val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
                constraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
                constraintSet.connect(
                    radioGroupList[index].id,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP,
                    constraintLayoutList[index].id,
                    ConstraintSet.TOP,
                    0
                )
                constraintSet.connect(
                    radioGroupList[index].id,
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                    constraintLayoutList[index].id,
                    ConstraintSet.BOTTOM,
                    0
                )

                constraintSet.connect(
                    radioGroupList[index].id,
                    ConstraintSet.END,
                    constraintLayoutList[index].id,
                    ConstraintSet.END,
                    0
                )


                if (index == constraintLayoutList.size-1){
                    testBtn.updateLayoutParams<ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams> {
                        topToTop = constraintLayoutList[index].id
                        bottomToBottom = constraintLayoutList[index].id
                        startToEnd = textViewList[index].id
                    }
                }
                constraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
                constraintLayoutList[index].requestLayout()
            }
               
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        for (parent in constraintLayoutList){
            parent.removeAllViews()
        }
        constraintLayoutList.clear()
        radioButtonList.clear()
        dataList.clear()
        textViewList.clear()
        radioGroupList.clear()
        binding.checkboxContainer.removeAllViews()
    }
}
```

I had two thoughts. The first one is that there was an error due to data remaining in the fragment. The other one is that the layouts were created correctly, but for some unknown reason, the constraintSetting didn't work, resulting in overlapping layouts.

I called the corresponding code in the navigation to solve the first issue, but it was ineffective.

//I understand that popUpTo is used to remove a fragment from the back stack.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_ble_test"
        android:name="com.skylabs.pba_mes.ui.main.BleTestFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ble_test">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragment_ble_test_to_fragment_scan_ble"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_scan_ble"
            app:popUpTo="@id/fragment_scan_ble"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
```

To solve the second issue, I tried changing the constraint settings multiple times when creating the constraintLayout, but it still didn't work.

If it doesn't work from the beginning, then it shouldn't work at all. If it works well, then it should work consistently until the end. I don't understand why it works only initially and then stops working afterwards.